# How to create Mesh based on a JSON-Object in three.js

Tags: json, ajax, three.js

I have an ajax request which helps me to get a JSON-object from a webserver!

```
function _loadModel(filename) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", filename);//open(method, url, async)
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.info(request.readyState +' - '+request.status);
        if (request.readyState == 4) {//4 == finished download
            if(request.status == 200) { //OK -> bezogen auf http Spezifikation
                handleLoadedGeometry(filename,JSON.parse(request.responseText));
            }
            else if (document.domain.length == 0 && request.status == 0){ //OK but local, no web server
                handleLoadedGeometry(filename,JSON.parse(request.responseText));
            }
            else{
                alert ('There was a problem loading the file :' + filename);
                alert ('HTML error code: ' + request.status);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();// send request to the server (used for GET)
}
_loadModel('http://localhost:8080/bbox?XMIN=3500060&YMIN=5392691&XMAX=3500277&YMAX=5393413')
```

**JSON file:**

`[{"building_nr": 5, "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[3500267.16,5392933.95,456.904],[3500259.19,5392933.01,456.904],[3500258.586,5392938.152,456.904],[3500258.02,5392942.97,456.904],[3500265.98,5392943.94,456.904],[3500266.552,5392939.097,456.904],[3500267.16,5392933.95,456.904]]]}", "polygon_typ": "BuildingGroundSurface"}, ...]`

This is one object and I have a lot of them in this array.

Now I want to create a mesh!
I think this can be done inside the function handleLoadedGeometry()

```
//Callback funktion
function handleLoadedGeometry(filename, model) {

    var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        vertex.x = model.geometry[i].coordinates[0];
        vertex.y = model.geometry[i].coordinates[1];
        vertex.z = model.geometry[i].coordinates[2];
        geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
    }

    geom.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00f0 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, material );
    Scene.scene.add(mesh);
}
```

At the end I get this error in the browser: **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

How can I refer to `geometry coordinates` inside the `JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

from what you provided it seems the loaded JSON contains an array of multiple objects that is why you get the error

try something like this

```
function handleLoadedGeometry(filename, models) {

    for (var i=0; i<models.length; i++)
    {
        var model = models[i];
        var coordinates = model.geometry.coordinates;
        var positions = [];
        for (var j=0; j<coordinates.length; j++){
           positions.push(coordinates[j][0]);
           positions.push(coordinates[j][1]);
           positions.push(coordinates[j][2]);
        }
        var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        // buffer attributes contain an array not vectors
        var positionAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions),3);
        geometry.addAttribute("position", positionAttribute);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00f0 } );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, material );     
        Scene.scene.add(mesh);
    }         
}
```

or remove the first loop if you call it for each object in the JSON array

Comment: thanks for your comment! but now I have a problem because model.geometry is a big string in my case: geometry: ""{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3500267.16,5392933.95,456.904],[3500259.19,5392933.01,456.904],[3500258.586,5392938.152,456.904],[3500258.02,5392942.97,456.904],[3500265.98,5392943.94,456.904],[3500266.552,5392939.097,456.904],[3500267.16,5392933.95,456.904]]]}". if i wanna select model.geometry.ccordinates it is unknown i can only select model.geometry.

Comment: then try another JSON.parse call on it or the json might have errors

Answer (score 0):

I did it in another way...I just created instead of BufferGeometry the default Geometry in three.js:

```
function handleLoadedGeometry(filename) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});

    for (var i=0; i<filename.length; i++)
    {
        var model = filename[i]; // erstes Objekt
        var coordinates = JSON.parse(model.geometry);
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var coordinates_updated =  _transformCoordinates(coordinates.coordinates[0]);

        for (var j = 0; j<coordinates_updated.vertices.length; j++){


            geometry.vertices.push(
                //new THREE.Vector3(coordinates.coordinates[0][j][0], coordinates.coordinates[0][j][1], coordinates.coordinates[0][j][2])//x,y,z Koordinatenpunkte für Surface 1
                new THREE.Vector3(coordinates_updated.vertices[j][0],coordinates_updated.vertices[j][1],coordinates_updated.vertices[j][2])
            );
            geometry.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3(0,1,2),
                new THREE.Face3(0,3,2)

            geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        }
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        Scene.scene.add(mesh);
    }
};
```

And now it works!
I think BufferGeometry is more for more complex surfaces.